# Using operator const char* in ostream

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

I am trying to Overload operator `<<` so the Error can be printed using `cout`. I need to print the `c-string` pointed by `m_messag`e. Can anyone help me solve this ?

`My Error.h` header :

```
ifndef ICT_ERROR_H_
#define ICT_ERROR_H_

#include <iostream>
namespace ict {
   class Error {
      char* m_message;
   public:
   // constructors
       Error();
       Error(const char* errorMessage);
   // destructor
       virtual ~Error();
   // deleted constructor and operator=
       Error(const Error& em) = delete;
       Error& operator=(const Error& em) = delete;
   // operator= for c-style strings
       void operator=(const char* errorMessage);
   // methods
       void clear();
       bool isClear()const;
       void message(const char* value);
   // cast overloads
       operator const char*() const;
       operator bool()const;
   };
   // operator << overload prototype for cout
   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Error& E);
}
#endif

Error.cpp

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <cstring>
#include "Error.h"

namespace ict{
    Error::Error()
    {
        m_message = nullptr;
    }
    Error::Error(const char * errorMessage)
    {
        m_message = nullptr;
        message(errorMessage);

    }
    Error::~Error()
    {
        delete[] m_message;
    }
    void Error::operator=(const char * errorMessage)
    {
        clear();
        message(errorMessage);
    }
    void Error::clear()
    {
        delete[] m_message;
        m_message = nullptr;
    }
    bool Error::isClear() const
    {
        bool status = false;
        if (m_message==nullptr) {
            status = true;
        }
        return status;
    }
    void Error::message(const char * value)
    {
        delete[] m_message;
        m_message = new char[strlen(value)+1];
        strcpy(m_message,value);
    }
    Error::operator const char*() const
    {

        return m_message;
    }
    Error::operator bool() const
    {
        return isClear();
    }
     ***std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Error& E) {
        if (E.isClear()) {

        }
        return os << E.operator const char *();

    }***
}

Main.cpp

int main(){
  Error T("Testing Error Message"); 
  cout << T << endl ;

}
```

When i execute it , it gives the correct output but it crashes with the following error :

> > Exception thrown: read access violation.
>
> _First was nullptr.

Debugger :

```
 static size_t __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL length(const _Elem *_First)
            {   // find length of null-terminated string
   //next statement to be executed ---> return (*_First == 0 ? 0
                 : _CSTD strlen(_First));
            }
```

Comment: And when you stepped through your code using a debugger, on which line did your debugger claim the exception occured?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik    I am sorry , i am not very familiar with Visual c++ debugger , but it seems it point me to the debugger code above instead of a specific line in my Error.cpp file

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i think the problem is on line 57 :  return os << E.operator const char *() when it gets eprinted on line 17 on main.cpp : cout << T << endl ;

Comment: @SamVarshavchik   Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @elvisi27 You can go around all this trouble with `const char*` if you use `std::string`. It does actually similar things like your class. This would make a lot of code unnecessary. (And, it does support stream I/O.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied all your code into one file to find out what's wrong. The test in `operator << ()` (whether error is clear) was missing. However, in your test this branch should not become active.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 

namespace ict {
   class Error {
      char* m_message;
   public:
   // constructors
       Error();
       Error(const char* errorMessage);
   // destructor
       virtual ~Error();
   // deleted constructor and operator=
       Error(const Error& em) = delete;
       Error& operator=(const Error& em) = delete;
   // operator= for c-style strings
       void operator=(const char* errorMessage);
   // methods
       void clear();
       bool isClear()const;
       void message(const char* value);
   // cast overloads
       operator const char*() const;
       operator bool()const;
   };
   // operator << overload prototype for cout
   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Error& E);
} // namespace ict


namespace ict{
    Error::Error()
    {
        m_message = nullptr;
    }
    Error::Error(const char * errorMessage)
    {
        m_message = nullptr;
        message(errorMessage);

    }
    Error::~Error()
    {
        delete[] m_message;
    }
    void Error::operator=(const char * errorMessage)
    {
        clear();
        message(errorMessage);
    }
    void Error::clear()
    {
        delete[] m_message;
        m_message = nullptr;
    }
    bool Error::isClear() const
    {
        bool status = false;
        if (m_message==nullptr) {
            status = true;
        }
        return status;
    }
    void Error::message(const char * value)
    {
        delete[] m_message;
        m_message = new char[strlen(value)+1];
        strcpy(m_message,value);
    }
    Error::operator const char*() const
    {

        return m_message;
    }
    Error::operator bool() const
    {
        return isClear();
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Error& E) {
      if (E.isClear()) return os;
      return os << E.operator const char *();
    }
} // namespace ict

int main(){
  ict::Error T("Testing Error Message"); 
  std::cout << T << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with VS2013 on Windows 10 (64 bit) and started the debugger.

As you see I added `return 0;` in `main()`. Actually, it is allowed to leave it out but it's a good point to place a breakpoint. Thus, I got the following output:

```
Testing Error Message
```

Hmm. So, where is the issue you described? I don't like the design (a matter of taste) but it works as expected. I looked for potential leaks or bugs:

If `Error::message()` is called with a `nullptr` then `strlen()` (and `strcpy()`) will probably crash. If you document the API with something like "Do not call `Error::message()` with a `nullptr`." I would find this sufficient.

Either you didn't provide all information or you didn't test *this* sample in your debugger.

What you really need to know is how your debugger works:

- Clicking in the gray bar left of text editor(s) places a break point. In debug mode the execution will stop (automatically) at break points. The respective source code is made visible (raising the editor tab and scrolling the text appropriately.
- **F9** ... toggle break point in current line
- **F10** ... step over (single step - execute functions as one statement)
- **F11** ... step in (single step - enter functions)
- **Shift** **F11** ... step out (execute code until return from current function)
- **F5** ... execute code (continuously until break point)

All these commands are available in menu bar and on toolbar. However, debugging is more convenient remembering the above keys.

Also, become familiar with [Local, Watch, and Call Stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx).

Comment: It seems all it needed to work was just adding "return os ;" after if (E.isclear())  . Thanks a lot for your help with the debugger also.